# How do I make every TR tag in a table a link with Perl and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, perl

If I have a  tag called "post" and has href="something from perl" what should i use for javascript in order to make it clickable and redirects me to the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you implement jQuery you can do something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $(".click").click(function() {
            window.document.location = $(this).attr("href");
      });
});
```

*edit*

assuming your tag looks like this

```
<tr class = "click" href = "<%= something from Perl %>">
```

Comment: code smell - use `this.href` instead of `$(this).attr('href')`